typescript generic type for record fields intersection
I'm trying to implement such a component:
const ConditionalWrapperWithCommon = <FirstProps extends Record<string, any>, SecondProps extends Record<string, any>>({
    commonProps,
    secondProps,
    Second,
    firstProps,
    First,
    children,
    condition,
}: TComponentWithCommonProps<FirstProps, SecondProps>) => {
    //error here is assignable to the constraint of type FirstProps, but FirstProps could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint Record<string, any>
    const mergedFirstProps: FirstProps = {
        ...commonProps,
        firstProps,
    };

    //error here
    const mergedSecondProps: SecondProps = {
        ...commonProps,
        secondProps,
    };

    return (
        <>
            {condition ? <First {...mergedFirstProps}>{children}</First> : <Second {...mergedSecondProps}>{children}</Second>}
        </>
    );
};

type TComponentWithCommonProps<FirstProps, SecondProps> = {
    condition: boolean;
    First: React.FC<FirstProps>;
    Second: React.FC<SecondProps>;
    firstProps: Omit<FirstProps, Extract<keyof FirstProps, keyof SecondProps>>;
    secondProps: Omit<SecondProps, Extract<keyof FirstProps, keyof SecondProps>>;
    commonProps: Pick<FirstProps & SecondProps, Extract<keyof FirstProps, keyof SecondProps>>;
    children?: React.ReactNode;
};

it's meant to be conditional wrapper with ability to extract common fields for both First and Second components.
the typing for "client usage" works perfectly fine, but inside the component itself I receive typing errors.
Is there some way I can improve my typings?
It seems to me, that I need some kind of Intersect<T,U> type so that I can use it for commonProps
